# Builtin module not found when executing python script from cmd (python 3.6.5)

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, cmd

Please can you help, I am trying to run a python script from Windows cmd. The error message I get is:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import __builtin__ as builtins
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\IndexTrader\code\futures_calc.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    import http.client as httplib
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinPython\python3.6.5.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
```

I run the python script within `Spyder` and `python` and the code executes with no problem or errors.

I am not sure what builtin package it is referring to. I beleieve the issue is with the `pandas` package *(which I uninstalled and reinstalled)*.

I have successfully run the script from `cmd` before, so I am not sure what the issue is. I have also reinstalled `WinPython`, but this has not helped.

I am not sure what to do, I checked the system paths and everything is in order, I also added a `PYTHONPATH` as a System variable, but no luck.

Any ideas?